# list directories and files without using the java.io package

Tags: java

I'm trying to list all the directories and files on windows mobile but I can't use the java.io package because it's not supported.
Does anyone have an idea if there is some other package I can use.

Thanks for the help.

Dim

Comment: Details on platform and version of java mobile please. There are several flavours on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call something like cmd.exe on Win Mobile?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external Java API, I highly recommend [EntityFS](http://www.entityfs.org/). It's an object oriented file system API for Java.